# Circular dependency between entities

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

i have three entities TestUser , TestProfile and TestPhoto in which TestUser has a OneToOne relationship with TestProfile and TestProfiles has a OneToOne relationship with TestPhoto and at the las TestPhoto has this ManyToOne relationship with User which might has not been created yet

im using cascade when defining my entites and i wish to have them all get created with a single call in my UserService but facing this Cyclic dependency: "TestPhoto" Error and had no progress since then , i see its not probably what is should do  in real life scenarios but apart from that ,any possible hack for it or its just fundamentally not possible?

```
@Entity()
@Unique(["name"])
export class TestUser {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @OneToOne(() => TestProfile,{
        cascade:true,
        nullable:true
    })
    @JoinColumn()
    profile: TestProfile;
    @Column({nullable:true})
    profileId: number

    @OneToMany(() => TestPhoto, photo => photo.user)
    photos: TestPhoto[];

}


@Entity()
export class TestProfile {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    gender: string;

    @OneToOne(type=>TestPhoto,{
        cascade:true,
        nullable:true
    })
    @JoinColumn()
    photo: TestPhoto;

    @Column({nullable:true})
    photoId: number

}

@Entity()
export class TestPhoto {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    url: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => TestUser, user => user.photos,{
        cascade:true,
        nullable:true
    })
    user: TestUser;
    @Column({nullable:true})
    userId: number; 

}
```

and in my UserService abstracted the calls as followed

```
const user = new TestUser(); 
const profile1 = new TestProfile(); 
const photo1 = new TestPhoto(); 
photo1.user = user;
profile1.photo  = photo1; 
user.profile = profile1

await connection.manager.save(user);
```

Comment: Can you share your Usermodule

Comment: @Youba don't have a Usermodule its just playing around nothing serious,only this three entities being used in the service method

Answer (score 3):

Does these entities are living in the same file?

I use [`import type`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html) TS's feature to resolve cyclic dependencies at module resolution level. I'm not sure if that is your case tho.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue with typeorm **Relation** as explaine here [tyopeorm entities circular dependencies](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4526#issuecomment-1076462998)

Answer (score 0):

Before you write code please feel free to understand the concept of circular dependency; [Link](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency). It is possible to have circular dependency in your case but might not be in real life scenarios. What you have to do is make your Entity/Modal a forwardRef on both side. Then make services inject-able to others using `@Inject(forwardRef(() => YourService))` inside constructor of another service. If you did not get an idea I will post a complete example of how circular dependency works in your case and in real life scenarios.

Comment: thanks @mudassirijaz786 i know whats circular dependency is in the layer of  service/module s but notice that we are actually talking about entities here not services . records in database cant have such forwardRefs , can't get done in a single database query

Answer (score 0):

I use a ***common import file*** when there is a circular dependency problem:

```
// common.ts
// also it's important to keep order, parent first and then...
export * from './parent.entity';
export * from './child1.entity';
export * from './child2.entity';

// parent.entity.ts ------------------------------------
import { Child1Entity, Child2Entity } from './common.ts'

export class ParentEntity {
    @OneToOne(() => Child1Entity, child => child.parent)
    public child1: Child1Entity[];

    @OneToOne(() => Child2Entity, child => child.parent)
    public child2: Child2Entity[];
}

// child1.entity.ts ----------------------
import { ParentEntity } from './common.ts'

export class Child1Entity extends Parent {
    @OneToOne(() => ParentEntity, parent => parent.child1)
    @JoinColumn()
    public parent: ParentEntity;
}

// child2.entity.ts ----------------------
import { ParentEntity } from './common.ts'

export class Child2Entity extends Parent {
    @OneToOne(() => ParentEntity, parent => parent.child2)
    @JoinColumn()
    public parent: ParentEntity;
}
```

> This pattern can help you with various circular dependency problems

Answer (score 0):

In Typeorm, the relationship decorators(@OneToMany, @ManyToOne, @OneToOne and ManyToMany) accept the following parameters:

```
export declare function OneToMany<T>(typeFunctionOrTarget: string | ((type?: any) => ObjectType<T>), inverseSide: string | ((object: T) => any), options?: RelationOptions): PropertyDecorator;
```

As you can see you can provide **typeFunctionOrTarget** (the first parameter) type as string, and it prevents the Typeorm circular dependency error.
In my case the following method solved the circular dependency issue:

```
@OneToMany(
    'CollectionPhase',
    (collectionPhase: CollectionPhase) => collectionPhase.collectionNo,
  )
  phases?: Relation<CollectionPhase[]>;
```